# Pandas dataframe hist not plotting catgorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe where i want to plot the histograms of each column.

```
df_play = pd.DataFrame({'a':['cat','dog','cat'],'b':['apple','orange','orange']})
df_play['a'] = df_play['a'].astype('category')
df_play['b'] = df_play['b'].astype('category')

df_play
df_play.hist(layout = (12,10))
```

However im getting `ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 0, not 1`
When i tried with integers instead of category in the values, it worked fine but i really want the names of the unique string to be in the x-axis.

Comment: Not that it changes the error message but your second and third lines do nothing: `df_play['a'].astype('category')` does not change `df_play['a']` (but returns a `Series` which you can replace your original one with).

Comment: Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply `pd.value_counts` across columns and plot.

```
>>> df_play.apply(pd.value_counts).T.stack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

If you want proper subplots or something more intricate, I'd suggest you just iterate with `value_counts` and create the subplots yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no natural parameter for binning, perhaps what you want rather than histograms are bar plots of the [value counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for each `Series`? If so, you can achieve that through

```
df_play['a'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: Example bar plot]

Comment: Is it possible to have `column a`  and `b` as subplots?

Comment: Is the intention that the Series share categories? If so, `df_play.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).plot(kind='bar', subplots=True)` might do what you are looking for.

Comment: @fugledge no they should be separate and not share categories

Answer (score 0):

I realized a way to do this is to first specify the fig and axs then loop though the column names of the dataframe that we want to plot the value counts.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,len(df_play.columns),figsize(10,6))
for i,x in enumerate(df_play.columns):
    df_play[x].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',ax=axs[i])
```

[image]